# Serilog - can not log to multiple files based on property

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog, rollingfilesink

Hello i am trying to log some messages in a file and others in another file using `Serilog`.

I have tried the following configuration:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.Map("type", "audit", (name, x) => x.File(auditLogPath))
                    .WriteTo.Map("type", "normal", (nm, wt) => wt.File(logpath).WriteTo.Console())
                    .CreateLogger();
```

Now i am expecting that when i `Push` a key-value pair with the key being `audit` to the log context , my data to get logged in the first pattern `audit`:

```
using(LogContext.PushProperty("type","audit")
{
    Log.Information("something");
}
```

Why does my data get in the second pattern? Its getting logged to console and put in the other file and i do not get why.

**Update**

From the answer below i understood there is no need to define multiple loggers, but dispatch based on the `key`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .WriteTo.Map("type", string.Empty, (nm, wt) => {
                      if (nm == "audit") {
                        wt.File(auditLogPath);  //i want to write here !
                        return;
                      }
                      wt.File(logpath).WriteTo.Console()                                                                                
                   })
             .CreateLogger();
```

However when i try to use it to log in the first scenario `audit` like below, all logs get placed in the other scenario (`logpath`+ `Console`)

```
using(LogContext.PushProperty("type","audit"))
{
    Log.Information("something");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood what the second parameter of `Map` is. It's not a filter... It's just a default value for your `keyPropertyName`, in case it's not present in the log event.

The decision to select the sink based on the value of the `type` property has to be done by you in the body of the `Map` configuration.

e.g.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Map("type", string.Empty, (type, wt) =>
    {
        if (type.Equals("audit"))
        {
            wt.File(auditLogPath);
        }
        else if (type.Equals("normal"))
        {
            wt.File(logPath)
                .WriteTo.Console();
        }
    })
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Also notice that without enabling enrichment via `LogContext` the properties you're pushing wouldn't be visible to `Map`, so you need the `.Enrich.FromLogContext()` above.

Comment: So you are saying i do not need to use `Map` two times ? Basically i should use multiple `Map` when i have multiple `key`-s that need matching.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Correct

Comment: So i have used the configuration you provided but somehow the `type` in the delegate never gets `audit` even though i use `LogContext.PushProperty("type","audit")` when writing to the logger.They all get put in the `logPath`.

Comment: You forgot to add the `.Enrich.FromLogContext()` ... Read the last sentence in my answer